# very slow action on loading a xmlhttp requested web page on another server?

Tags: regex, asp-classic, xmlhttprequest

```vb
url="http://www.noktadomains.com/searchdomain.html?length.max=2&length.min=2&page=1"
Set strhttp=server.createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
strhttp.Open "get",url,false
strhttp.send
gethttp=strhttp.responsetext

gethttp=Mid(gethttp,instr(gethttp,"<tbody>"),instr(gethttp,"</tbody>")-instr(gethttp,"<tbody>")+8)

Set RegExte=New RegExp
RegExte.Global=True
RegExte.IgnoreCase = False
RegExte.Pattern="trackEvent,SearchPageLink,Search,([\d\D\w][^.]{0,70}).([\d\D\w][^\]]{0,20})"
Set Sonucte=RegExte.Execute(gethttp)
if sonucte.count>0 then
  for i=0 to sonucte.count-1
    response.write(i+1&"-"&Sonucte(i).SubMatches(0)&"."&Sonucte(i).SubMatches(1)&"<br>")
  next
end if
```

I have an .ASP page and with that code above, I got the source code from that url:

"*noktadomains.com/**searchdomain.html?length.max=2&length.min=2&page=1***"

Output on my .asp page is like;

```
1-00.co
2-00.org
3-00000.org
4-000WebHosting.com
5-0033.co
6-007BondGirls.com
7-007Movie.com
8-...
```

Until here everything is ok, I do what I want, but I have problem with time, when my asp page is loading, it takes at least 7-8 seconds, and I guess because the target URL that I connect with xmlhttp is very large and because of that it takes a long time?

Any idea for that situation?

Comment: Writing this `[\d\D\w]` has no sense. Use an html parser.

Comment: Should i replace it, to make correct my regexp pattern?

Comment: No, remove all the regex part of your code, and search all links that have the class "domain" with an XPath query (for example). Then extract and trim the text content for each link.